# Overriding modena selectors in a style sheet

Tags: css, javafx

I have a Javafx application for which I wish to add functionality to change colour schemes.  The app uses modena.css as the default style sheet.

If I override -fx-color in a separate style sheet on the scene eg.

```
.root {
  -fx-color:black;
}
```

do selectors that depend on -fx-color get redefined? eg.

```
   -fx-inner-border: linear-gradient(to bottom,
                ladder(
                    -fx-color,
                    derive(-fx-color,30%) 0%,
                    derive(-fx-color,20%) 40%,
                    derive(-fx-color,25%) 60%,
                    derive(-fx-color,55%) 80%,
                    derive(-fx-color,55%) 90%,
                    derive(-fx-color,75%) 100%
                ),
                ladder(
                    -fx-color,
                    derive(-fx-color,20%) 0%,
                    derive(-fx-color,10%) 20%,
                    derive(-fx-color,5%) 40%,
                    derive(-fx-color,-2%) 60%,
                    derive(-fx-color,-5%) 100%
                ));
```

or do I have to redefine these in my style sheet to ensure they use the new value of -fx-color?

Comment: Redefined? No. Does the value calculated based on the rule using this lookedup color get updated? Yes.

Comment: Redefined maybe the wrong term, but the answer is what I want. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comment from @fabian each selector is evaluated when used so in this case -fx-inner-border will use the updated -fx-color.